Searching the LaTeX Font Catalog for a specific Unicode character?
Is there any way to search the LaTeX Font Catalog to find which fonts contain the specific character '⌘' (Unicode u+2318)? Any other ways to identify which fonts contain this character?
The suggestion in the comments to use albatross does not provide an answer to my question. While I didn't know about this command, and it's very useful, it does not provide a way to search the LaTeX Font Catalog for a specific Unicode character, which was the original question. [Sorry for my over-enthusiasm in promising to accept the answer of albatross. I didn't understand it at first, and was so impressed with what it did, that I didn't examine it thoroughly.]

texlive includes a command albatross and abatross U+2318 will list all the fonts on your system that have this (or at least all the fonts it can find)

on my system I get  lots of variants of DejaVu (Sans, Sans Mono, Sans Condensed...) and not much else

@DavidCarlisle, thanks so much. This is just what I'm looking for. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

@DavidCarlisle, while I've got your attention, thank you so much for your work on The LaTeX Companion. I have the 2nd ed and refer to it frequently. Thank You!

We could summon Paulo to answer as he wrote the program:-)

I get more results than @DavidCarlisle if I include the l in albatross.

@cfr surely you are not implying that my typing skills are less than perfect?

As explained in comments on your other question:

The LaTeX Font Catalogue is a website rather than a database and it cannot be searched except using the usual methods for searching web pages. Moreover, the site provides samples of fonts. It does not provide an exhaustive list of the characters provided by each. So, while you could theoretically scrape the information and search it for a particular character, not finding that character for a particular font (or all of them) would not tell you the the font (or fonts) don't have it.
A full install of TeX Live contains all (or as close to all as makes no odds) the free fonts covered by the catalogue. The relevant sense of 'free' is free software. So freeware fonts are excluded, for example.
Most of the fonts listed in the catalogue are free in the relevant sense. Indeed, the vast majority are free.
The upshot is that searching an installation of TeX Live for a character will detect almost all, if not all, fonts in the catalogue which have that character.
albatross is the best available tool for searching an installed TeX Live for a character.
Hence, albatross is the best practical answer to your question, even though it is not a perfect answer and its being the best practical answer is relative to the current state of various things which might or might not change at some point.

Note that the manual page for albatross is not accurate. Us albatross --help to get a listing of current options.
albatross --include-tex-fonts --detailed <characters>

will provide a detailed listing you could process further. This will not include fonts which are non-Unicode. The best way I know to find symbols in those fonts remains
texdoc comprehensive

The listing from albatross will include fonts from outside the TeX tree. If you want only those in the TeX tree, you could use
albatross --include-tex-fonts ...

and
albatross ...

and compare the redirected outputs using your favourite incarnation of diff.
Note that it is not entirely clear why you want to search for fonts in the LaTeX Font Catalogue in particular. Typically people want to search for fonts available to them e.g. installed or readily installable. If a font was missing from the Catalogue but installed as part of TeX Live on your machine would you want it excluded?

I originally wanted to search the LaTeX Font catalog because I thought it was an exhaustive listing of all the fonts available to LaTeX. I'm not very knowledgeable about fonts on LaTeX, and this was my impression. I also didn't understand that most of the fonts in the LaTeX Catalog are installed on a system with texlive-full.  Thank you for your very complete and knowledgeable answer.

@KevinZembower you're welcome, though really it is just a summary of the comments (hence community wiki).
